# Find max value from the table values

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write the query to find the max value from the table value.

Table structure as follows,

```
col  col2  col3
1    a1    20150102
2    c1    20150201
3    a1    20150301
4    c1    20150101
```

I want the result as follows

### output: table1

```
c1 = 20150201
a1 = 20150301
```

### my query:

```
Select * from table1 where col3 = (select max(col3) from table1);
```

Comment: `select col2,max(col3) as col3 from table_name group by col2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and the `MAX` function.

```
SELECT col2, MAX(col3)
FROM table1
GROUP BY col2
```

Output

```
col2    MAX(col3)
a1      20150301
c1      20150201
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73026/1/0

Answer (score 0):

this way also we can do using Row_number

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (col int, col2 varchar(2), col3 int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (col, col2, col3)
VALUES
    (1, 'a1', 20150102),
    (2, 'c1', 20150201),
    (3, 'a1', 20150301),
    (4, 'c1', 20150101)
;

select T.col2,T.col3 from @Table1 T 
INNER JOIN (select RN from (select (ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col3))RN from @Table1)T GROUP BY T.RN )TT ON T.col = TT.RN
ORDER BY T.col2 DESc
```